# Problem importing geodata from file GDB with geopandas in python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas, fiona, geopackage

I'm working on some code to select and export geodata based on a bounding box. The data I want to select comes from 2 seperate layers in a huge File GDB (16GB) covering the entire Netherlands. I use a bounding box as to avoid reading the entire dataset before making a selection.

This method works great when applied on a gpkg database, but with a file geodatabase the time to process is way longer (0,2s vs 300s for a 200x200 meter selection). The File GDB I'm using has a spatial index set for the layers I'm reading. I'm using geopandas to read and select. Below you'll find an example for the layer 'Adres':

```
import geopandas as gpd

def ImportGeodata(FilePath, BoundingBox):
    importBag=gpd.read_file(FilePath, layer='Adres', bbox=BoundingBox)
    importBag['mergeid']=importBag['identificatie']
    return importBag
```

Am I overseeing something? Or is this a limitation when importing from a huge File GDB? I can't find an obvious mistake here. For now the workaround is another script that imports and dumps the layers I need in a gpkg. Problem is this runs for 3 to 4 hours (gpkg result is almost 6 GB). I don't want to keep doing that, it would be necessary to do once every month or so in order to process a new version of this dataset.

Curious what you guys come up with.

Comment: I assume that fiona, used in geopandas to read files does not support gdb as well as it does support gpkg. Maybe spatial indexing is not used in reading? There's certainly no mistake in your code.

Comment: I tried both the 'OpenFileGDB' and 'FileGDB' (default) drivers by the way, forgot to tell this. In the Fiona documentation I do find that Fiona supports spatial indexing in file GDBs, so I'm still puzzled.